# java.awt.Robot не двигает курсор в Photoshop

Tags: java, photoshop

Нужно, чтобы java могла двигать курсор в photoshop. Java умеет двигать курсор и делает это нормально в остальных приложениях, но когда окно photoshop активно, то java ничего почему-то сделать не может. Курсор стоит на месте и сдвигается только от мышки. windows.h на c++ тоже не помог. Наверно нужно имитировать ввод, но как это сделать я не знаю. Готов использовать другой язык, если это необходимо... Photoshop SDK - не вариант.

Comment: Вам нужен хороший кликер или вы хотите сами написать чтоб чтот рисовало?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Т.к. все приложения, с которыми возникали проблемы, были запущены от имени администратора, то и приложение надо было запустить от имени администратора

Answer (score 0):

### *Ваши косяки:*

1) Вы используете кроссплатворменный ЯП для написания программы, работающей с WinAPI - не надо так, лучше воспользуетесь плюсами или delphi для этих целей

2) А вы уверены, что события мышки в photoshop совпадают с событиями в обычных приложениях (я вот не уверен, т.к. там несколько областей и панелей, которые как-то хитро связаны) Здесь вам поможет Spy++ (Messages) и его аналоги.

3)

> This class is used to generate **native system input events** for the **purposes of test automation**, self-running demos, and other applications where control of the mouse and keyboard is needed.

Как видим, даже создатели рекомендуют использовать только для тестов...
Что логично, ведь программа может помимо стандартных, обрабатывать нестандартные сообщения. (You shoul use **SendMessage**)

-

### *Как бы я сделал:*

1) Поискал бы другой способ решения проблемы (плагины для фотошопа или что-то другое), т.к. работать с формами из-под WinAPI - не надежно!

2) Если все же другого выхода нет - открыл бы Spy++ и изучил строение программы, ее Messages и логику. На основе полученной информации построил бы логические цепочки для нужных мне операций.

3) Выбор наиболее удобного ЯП.

4) Используя полученные цепочки реализовал бы взаимодействие на основе SendMessage

Comment: Спасибо. Но я пишу  приложение, которое будет эмулировать тачпад/графический планшет. Мне хотелось бы имитировать ввод. Плагины не очень подходят. Есть ли способ именно эмулировать мышь

Comment: @AlexSergeev, Вы прочитали или пробежались глазами по моему ответу?

Comment: Там черным по белому

Comment: 1) Для эмуляции "тачпад/графический планшет" плагины отлично подходят, т.к. поддерживают имения в 99% модулей программы. Я писал когда-то плагин для порта photoshop на xbox classic...

Comment: 2) Вы не можете эмулировать мышь, т.к. такого понятия в WinAPI нет!!! НО, вы можете эмулировать сообщения, которые отсылает мышь программе (для этого полностью прочтите мой ответ)

Comment: 3) Вы понимаете, что за подобную программу вас Adobe может засудить (я НЕ про плагин, но про SendMessage)'

Comment: Robot может работать с photoshop и диспетчером задач на win7, а на win10 не может(с диспетчером задач такая же проблема. Не сильно-то он мне и нужен, но вдруг эта информация поможет)